# Increase performance of SSIS Package dumping data from Excel to SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssis

I have created an SSIS Package that dumps data from Excel file to SQL Server table. The package is simply having 2 tasks:
Script Component Task & OLE DB Destination

[image: Package with 2 tasks to dump data from xlsx file to sql server table]

Please find below the code i have added in the script task:

```
/* Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Script Component
*  Write scripts using Microsoft Visual C# 2008.
*  ScriptMain is the entry point class of the script.*/

using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Xml;

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]


public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
    private OleDbDataReader excelReader;
    private OleDbConnection excelConnection;
    private OleDbCommand excelCommand;

    DataTable tablesInFile;
    string currentTable;

    public override void PreExecute()
    {
        base.PreExecute();
        GetDataFromExcelToReader(Variables.FilePath);

    }
    public override void PostExecute()
    {
        base.PostExecute();
        excelReader.Close();
        excelConnection.Close();
    }
    //private void GetDataFromExcelToReader(string p_strFileName, string p_strTabName)
    private void GetDataFromExcelToReader(string p_strFileName)
    {
        string l_strConnectionString;
        if (File.Exists(p_strFileName))
        {
            l_strConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
            "Data Source=" + p_strFileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\";";

            excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(l_strConnectionString);
            excelConnection.Open();
            tablesInFile = excelConnection.GetSchema("Tables");


            foreach (DataRow tableInFile in tablesInFile.Rows)
            {
                currentTable = tableInFile["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                break;
            }

            excelCommand = excelConnection.CreateCommand();
            //excelCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + p_strTabName + "A1:AX1048576]";
            excelCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + currentTable + "]";
            excelCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            excelReader = excelCommand.ExecuteReader();
        }
    }
    public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
    {
        int counter = 0;
        while (excelReader.Read())
        {
            Output0Buffer.AddRow();
            Output0Buffer.Source = Variables.Source.ToString();
            Output0Buffer.Column = excelReader.FieldCount > 0 ? excelReader[0].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column1 = excelReader.FieldCount > 1 ? excelReader[1].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column2 = excelReader.FieldCount > 2 ? excelReader[2].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column3 = excelReader.FieldCount > 3 ? excelReader[3].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column4 = excelReader.FieldCount > 4 ? excelReader[4].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column5 = excelReader.FieldCount > 5 ? excelReader[5].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column6 = excelReader.FieldCount > 6 ? excelReader[6].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column7 = excelReader.FieldCount > 7 ? excelReader[7].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column8 = excelReader.FieldCount > 8 ? excelReader[8].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column9 = excelReader.FieldCount > 9 ? excelReader[9].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column10 = excelReader.FieldCount > 10 ? excelReader[10].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column11 = excelReader.FieldCount > 11 ? excelReader[11].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column12 = excelReader.FieldCount > 12 ? excelReader[12].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column13 = excelReader.FieldCount > 13 ? excelReader[13].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column14 = excelReader.FieldCount > 14 ? excelReader[14].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column15 = excelReader.FieldCount > 15 ? excelReader[15].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column16 = excelReader.FieldCount > 16 ? excelReader[16].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column17 = excelReader.FieldCount > 17 ? excelReader[17].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column18 = excelReader.FieldCount > 18 ? excelReader[18].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column19 = excelReader.FieldCount > 19 ? excelReader[19].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column20 = excelReader.FieldCount > 20 ? excelReader[20].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column21 = excelReader.FieldCount > 21 ? excelReader[21].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column22 = excelReader.FieldCount > 22 ? excelReader[22].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column23 = excelReader.FieldCount > 23 ? excelReader[23].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column24 = excelReader.FieldCount > 24 ? excelReader[24].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column25 = excelReader.FieldCount > 25 ? excelReader[25].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column26 = excelReader.FieldCount > 26 ? excelReader[26].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column27 = excelReader.FieldCount > 27 ? excelReader[27].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column28 = excelReader.FieldCount > 28 ? excelReader[28].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column29 = excelReader.FieldCount > 29 ? excelReader[29].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column30 = excelReader.FieldCount > 30 ? excelReader[30].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column31 = excelReader.FieldCount > 31 ? excelReader[31].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column32 = excelReader.FieldCount > 32 ? excelReader[32].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column33 = excelReader.FieldCount > 33 ? excelReader[33].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column34 = excelReader.FieldCount > 34 ? excelReader[34].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column35 = excelReader.FieldCount > 35 ? excelReader[35].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column36 = excelReader.FieldCount > 36 ? excelReader[36].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column37 = excelReader.FieldCount > 37 ? excelReader[37].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column38 = excelReader.FieldCount > 38 ? excelReader[38].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column39 = excelReader.FieldCount > 39 ? excelReader[39].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column40 = excelReader.FieldCount > 40 ? excelReader[40].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column41 = excelReader.FieldCount > 41 ? excelReader[41].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column42 = excelReader.FieldCount > 42 ? excelReader[42].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column43 = excelReader.FieldCount > 43 ? excelReader[43].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column44 = excelReader.FieldCount > 44 ? excelReader[44].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column45 = excelReader.FieldCount > 45 ? excelReader[45].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column46 = excelReader.FieldCount > 46 ? excelReader[46].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column47 = excelReader.FieldCount > 47 ? excelReader[47].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column48 = excelReader.FieldCount > 48 ? excelReader[48].ToString() : null;
            Output0Buffer.Column49 = excelReader.FieldCount > 49 ? excelReader[49].ToString() : null;
        }
    }
}
```

Please find below snapshot of configuration done inside OLE DB Destination task:

[image: Configuration inside OLE DB Destination task]

Currently if I run the package for xlsx file containing around 99000 records, it takes 4mins to dump data in database which is quite large. Expectation is to complete the process in seconds.
How can I achieve this in seonds within this package. My Excel files would be dynamic and can contain minimum 1 record to maximum of 1.5 - 2 lacs record.

Please help. Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Making changes in OLE DB Destination task served my purpose and I was able to dramatically improve the performance.

I used the **Fast Load** option by tweaking couple of its properties. Now, I am able to dump 2laks records in about 15 secs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the performance point of view then I would suggest you to use the following:

1) Create a Exact same temp Table in database which will be dropped or truncated after the process is complete.

2) Insert the the records from excel source to TEMP TABLE.

3) Next Step, Get the record from TEMP TABLE and insert into your destination table.

Note: For the first step you can Drag the `Execute SQL Task`  either do it in Stored procedure or Just simple Query

Comment: Even if I create a temp table for same, it will only increase the time for whole process. First, 4 mins to load data in temp table and then from temp table to my destination table. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong anywhere ?

Comment: What did you do in order to load into temp table? Can you tell me the process?

Comment: I have not created any temp table yet. I have table in place in database. The whole process I am doing to dump data in that table from my excel file, I have defined in my question. Please tel me if i need to provide any more information.

Comment: So how can you tell without even trying. Create the first process in Stored Proc that will transfer the data to temp table and second one is to load the data from the temp table to Destination table.

Comment: I think there is slight bit of confusion out here. The reason I have done such a coding in script task is because my excel source files are dynamic. I have even mentioned that in my question. The script task is giving data to the output columns which are being mapped to sql server table columns. I hope this explains the whole scenario. I will appreciate if you could suggest something in script code or some configuration changes in OLE DB Destination task that helps us to load the data faster in destination table.